# How can I use Amazon Comprehend in Lua?

Tags: lua, amazon-comprehend

I want to use Amazon Comprehend to analyze some articles.

But there is no Lua SDK in the API Reference, neither Restful API. What should I do to use Amazon Comprehend in Lua code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Option 1

Use the AWS SDK for C++ and Lua's C/C++ API to build bindings you can use from Lua.

###### Option 2

Hack together something using `io.popen` and the AWS CLI.